# How to execute application on system startup using windows service in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I am working on VB.Net framework. I have a Windows Form Application that syncs the data to the server. Now I want to make it auto start at the time of System Startup. I tried to register it in system registry(regedit) but max of the time it fails to start my application at System Startup. Now someone suggest to make Windows Service and install it. But the thing is Windows Service doesn't support UI.
Now I am not able to make my application auto start or I did not find any way where I can integrate Both Apps(Windows Form App and Windows Service).
So, Please suggest me if there is any way to do so.

Comment: add the exe (or shortcut) to the start up folder? eg Run shell:startup

Comment: anything i want running on system startup i add to the task scheduler in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to make an application run in the startup is by copying your applications shortcut file into the startup folder.
Follow these steps:

1. Copy your application shortcut file.
2. Press **Windows Key + R** *This will open Run.*
3. Type:  **shell:startup**
4. Click **OK**
5. Paste your application shortcut in the folder which opens after Step 3.

Hope this helps :)